# Link active anchor class to page section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

How can I make the below site add the active class to each anchor link based upon the fullPage.js section displayed?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJrwbq.

HTML:

```
<nav>

    <ul id="menu">

        <li>

            <a>Menu</a>

            <div id="dropdown">

            <ul>

                <li class="navLink active"><a href="#home" data-menuanchor="homeSection"><span class="navNumber">01</span>Home</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a href="#about" data-menuanchor="aboutSection"><span class="navNumber">02</span>About</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a href="#skills" data-menuanchor="skillsSection"><span class="navNumber">03</span>Skills</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a href="#work" data-menuanchor="workSection"><span class="navNumber">04</span>Work</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a href="#contact" data-menuanchor="contactSection"><span class="navNumber">05</span>Contact</a></li>

            </ul>

            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>

    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navLink > a:hover,
.navLink.active > a,
.navLink.active > a > span
{
  color: #1957EF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fullPage.js provides a `menu` option that you can use for that as it is detailed [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

> **menu**: (default `false`) A selector can be used to specify the menu to link with the sections. This way the scrolling of the sections will activate the corresponding element in the menu using the class active. This won't generate a menu but will just add the active class to the element in the given menu with the corresponding anchor links. In order to link the elements of the menu with the sections, an HTML 5 data-tag (`data-menuanchor`) will be needed to use with the same anchor links as used within the sections. Example:

```
<ul id="myMenu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">First section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#thirdPage">Third section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="fourthPage"><a href="#fourthPage">Fourth section</a></li>
</ul>
```

In your initialization:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#myMenu'
});
```

Notice how the value of the `anchors` has to be the same as the `data-menuanchor`. In your case it isn't. You are using `about` and then `aboutSection`.
Also note the `active` class will be added to your `a` element and not to the `li` one.

Answer (score -1):

You need to look at scrollTop in jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

In a nutshell, you need to measure the scroll position from the top of the page, and if that position is equal to a certain number, use jQuery to add the active class to the link, otherwise remove it.

There are plenty of examples of this online, I'm sure you'll be able to find something!

Comment: fullPage.js provides plenty of better alternatives. Plus there's no scrollbar and therefore there's the scroll top property won't change.

Answer (score -1):

Try This - you can use [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to apply/remove class on any HTML tag.

You need to add below code in in your page

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".navLink").click(function(){
    $(".navLink").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });  
});
```